# How can I change the search page column layout in Magento 2.1 to one column?

Tags: magento2, layout, catalogsearch, advanced-search

I've been searching for a while and I am only finding answers [DevDocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html) that tell me that in order to modify the column layout for the search results page is to change the xml found in `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/Magento_CatalogSearch/layout/` 
My problem is that my folder structure for my theme does not have a layout folder.  Seems like  remember seeing the layout setting in the backend config somewhere, but cannot seem to find it there either.

Any search that I perform on my website is resulting in a 4-column layout and I only want a 1-column layout or maybe 2-column with left sidebar.  ...all the same for advanced search.

I am using Magento 2.1.4.

Comment: Overwrite `magento\vendor\magento\module-catalog-search\view\frontend\layout\catalogsearch_result_index.xml` & Change `layout="2columns-left"` to `layout="1column"`

Comment: @AnkitShah Never overwrite files in /vendor folder!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your theme create the `catalogsearch_result_index.xml` in following path: `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<your_theme>/Magento_CatalogSearch/layout/catalogsearch_result_index.xml`

Add the below content to xml file.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Advanced Search</title>
    </head>
</page>
```

This way you can set column layout for search result page.

EDIT:

If need 1 column layout, need to change in

```
layout="2columns-left"
```

to

```
layout="1column"
```

Comment: This solution worked as well.  I believe that I have another issue that is causing the width of the content section to be reduced below 100%.  Thanks for the help!